# AccessKey of Azure Storage created with Terraform are different from portal

Tags: azure, terraform

I use Terraform to create an Azure Storage account and I store the Access Keys (primary and secondary) in Azure Key Vault.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "StorageAccessKey" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault.kv,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.KVAccessPolicies
  ]
  name = "Azure--Storage--AccountKey"
  value = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_access_key
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

When I check the value from the Azure Portal, the Access key are different:

[image: Access key on Azure Portal for storage account]

[image: Accesskey in Azure Key Vault]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to store access key of Azure Storage account in Key Vault created with Terraform**

You can use below **Terraform** code to store the storage account access key in **Key vault**.

```
    provider  "azurerm" {

features {}

}
data  "azurerm_client_config"  "current" {}
resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "thejarg" {
name =  "theja-resource-group"

location =  "eastus"

}
resource  "azurerm_storage_account"  "thejastorageaccount123" {

name =  "thejastorageaccount1"

resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.thejarg.name

location =  azurerm_resource_group.thejarg.location

account_tier =  "Standard"

account_replication_type =  "LRS"
identity {

type =  "SystemAssigned"

}

}

resource  "azurerm_key_vault"  "thejavaulttest" {

name =  "thejavault"

resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.thejarg.name

location =  azurerm_resource_group.thejarg.location
sku_name =  "standard"

tenant_id =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

access_policy {

tenant_id =  "3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-1238b1a77336"

object_id =  "a970fc40-48da-4ac7-b126-b40206699b9c"

key_permissions =  ["Create","Get",]

secret_permissions =  ["Set","Get","Delete","Purge", "Recover","List"]

storage_permissions =  ["Get","Set"]

}

}

resource  "azurerm_key_vault_secret"  "primary_storage_key" {

name =  "primary-storage-key"

value =  azurerm_storage_account.thejastorageaccount123.primary_access_key

key_vault_id =  azurerm_key_vault.thejavaulttest.id

}
```

Once ran the above code resources are created successfully.

[image]

When I check the storage account access key in key vault, the same key is updated in key vault.

[image]

Comment: After destroying and re-create my resources, the key are now correct. Perhaps the iterative process make my keys not correctly saved.